# How to output a string state value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to output a state value that is a string, but I have no idea how. I have spent a long time searching and am getting really frustrated. Any help comrades?

Comment: Code Snippet will help

Comment: where do you want to put it? `<p>{this.state.value}</p>` or `<input type="text" value={this.state.value} />` ... or if you are using hooks: `const [value, setValue] = React.setState("string");  <p>{state}</p>;`

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the question, but should be as simple as adding it to your render function: `render() { return <div>{this.state.value}</div> }`

Comment: What about starting with the basics? Doing this is probably the first thing that you do when you start learning about React (and probably any other framework that works with state)

Answer (score -1):

Please refer to the following demo, you will get the idea, how to store the value into state and access value of the state. 
https://codesandbox.io/s/state-usage-svdoq